# auto increment with nested the serial number when row increases and automatically readjust the numbering order when a row gets deleted in angularjs

Tags: angularjs-directive

1 will be section and under section there are child like 1.1 subsection and under subsection there will be paragraph...

one section will have multiple subsection like

1
    1.1
      (a)
         (i)
         (ii)
          -----

```
1.2
   (i)
   (ii)
```

---

```
1.3
```

1

1.1

(a)

```
  (i)
  (ii)
  (iii)
  (iv)
```

(b)

```
 (i)
 (ii)
 (iii)
 (iv)
```

2
  2.1
   (a)

```
  (i)
  (ii)
  (iii)
  (iv)


(b)

 (i)
 (ii)
 (iii)
 (iv)
```

how to do this using angularjs

Comment: Please, provide your code.

Comment: There is no code for it...suggest me how to do it using angularjs